# How can i make soft access point on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-access-point

I want to share my LAN connection with other devices via wi-fi.
All i have is a Ubuntu 10.10, eth0 and wlan0 (wi-fi adapter: D-link DWA-510).
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link to the ubuntu doc on creating an access point: [WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint)

And here is a quicker solution using [hostapd](http://xsolvo.com/node/12)

Comment: unfortunately i have an error on "iwconfig" step, while trying to config hostapd: 
iwconfig wlan0 essid "mynewwap" mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.

Comment: i can't quite get the second link to work. I'd note while linking is good, a self contained answer would survive not being able to reach linked sites.

Comment: Actually, if you don't like the idea of writing a configuration file for `hostapd`, the popular NetworkManager tool also supports managing an AP now, but this is not available through its GUI tools; it requires a manual tweak in its configuration file for `mode=ap`. Reference in Russian: http://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.B0_.D0.B2_NetworkManager